# How to create a custom grouping of properties and apply them to different controls?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

I have a window with Buttons, TextFields, Labels etc. These all share common properties like font family, color, size etc. What I would like to be able to do is to define a grouping of these properties (called, say, textStyles.MainTitle or textStyles.DescriptiveText etc.) that would include a font family, size and weight, height and color. And then in the QML file I would write something like:

```
myCustomProperty: textStyles.MainTitle
```

and this would apply those values to the control. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

QML controls are styled by implementing their respective styles, for example for `Button` you have to implement a `ButtonStyle`.

As for the actual "grouping" you can just use a `QtObject`

```
property QtObject textStyles : QtObject {
    property FontLoader mainTitle : FontLoader {...}
    ....
}
```

You can also extend styled components as dedicated types:

// StyledText.qml

```
Text {
  font.family: someFont
  font.pixelSize: fontSize
  color: someColor
  font.italic: true
  font.letterSpacing: -1
  ...
}
```

And then use that by just `StyledText {}` instead of repeatedly styling regular `Text` elements.

> Where / in what file do I place the QtObject snippet? I don't understand what // StyledText.qml is, or what a FontLoader is.

If you want it to be available in your entire application, you can put it as a property of your root object in `main.qml`, thanks to dynamic scoping `textStyles` will resolve from every other file in your project. You can put entire component styles in it as well and share in the project.

`StyledText.qml` is just an extra qml file you add to your project, you can being with just implementing its body in an existing qml file, then rightclick on `Text` and select refactoring -> move component into separate file.

A `FontLoader` is just a regular QML component, you can use it to load specific fonts and use as a font source for text. You don't have to use that, you can use font families from your system fonts as well. The font loader is useful for fonts you bundle with your application.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen examples like this but I don't know how to implement them. Where / in what file do I place the QtObject snippet? I don't understand what // StyledText.qml is, or what a FontLoader is. I know that I can implement a ButtonStyle, a CheckBoxStyle etc. for each type of control. What I was hoping to do was to avoid repeating this code for each type of control, and instead be able to define a sort of enum that I can then set for any kind of control and have its font and color properties set thusly.

Comment: Sorry for being dense, but I still do not understand what I should put where (this is an inherited app and I do not really understand how it's structured). I do not have a main.qml file anywhere. It sounds like your second example of what to do (if there are even two example here, I'm not sure) is what I want to do. I have a file called LoginScreen.qml - do I put the Text {} block you mention in that file, above the Window {} section that is already there? How do I reference this block from elsewhere in the file?

Comment: I sort of get that the `Text {}` block overrides (or inherits?) whatever Text is in qml, but I don't get why it doesn't have some sort of unique identifier.

Comment: I don't think I'm describing what I'm trying to do very well. Essentially I am trying to define a variety of text styles (e.g. WindowTitle, SectionHeader, DescriptiveText etc.), where each style consists of a font, font.pixelSize and a color (e.g. "Arial", 16 and "red"). Then, for any qml control (Button, TextField etc.), I want to be able to write something like "myFontStyle = WindowTitle;" instead of setting those font and color properties directly.

Comment: @MusiGenesis once you put that `Text{}` object with a set of defined properties in its own qml file, for example `SomeText`, then it becomes a type of its own, so you can use `SomeText {}` to create text instances with the predefined properties. You can use it directly or as part of say a custom `ButtonStyle`

Comment: How would I use it as part of a ButtonStyle? inside the ButtonText definition is there something like text: StyledText {} ? Is there like a complete code sample online somewhere of how to do this? With my current setup I really can't easily experiment with this kind of thing, since anything that breaks the qml results in a just a little postage-stamp sized window for my app and no additional information. Every attempt I'm making to put your code examples anywhere is resulting in this.

Comment: @MusiGenesis the `ButtonStyle` element as a `label` property, this is where you put your styled text, like this: `ButtonStyle { label: StyledText ...etc... }`. When you have an error, the Creator console outputs the file and line where it occurred, as well as the the error type. Those are just basic things, if you have problems with them you are likely getting ahead of yourself. Do a little more learning before you try to use the language freely, this applies to any language, this way you will get better and less off-putting and confusing experience. QML is very simple but a little different.